# What is the difference between check a model and tranlate a model in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am using Dymola, but I am not sure about the difference between check a model and translate a model.
So I did a test.

Here is the code of the connector and the model file

```
connector Port
  flow Real Q;
  Real P;
  Real T;
end Port;
```

```
model Inlet
  parameter Real Q = 1;
  parameter Real P = 2;
  parameter Real T = 3;
  Port a;
equation 
  a.Q = Q;
  a.P = P;
  a.T = T;
end Inlet;
```

If I check the model, Dymola would generate a .mof file:

```
model lab.Inlet
parameter Real Q = 1;
parameter Real P = 2;
parameter Real T = 3;

Real a.Q;
Real a.P;
Real a.T;

// Equations and algorithms

  // Component 
  // class lab.Inlet
  equation
    a.Q = Q;
    a.P = P;
    a.T = T;

end lab.Inlet;
```

If I translate the model, the .mof file is like the following:

```
model lab.Inlet
parameter Real Q = 1;
parameter Real P = 2;
parameter Real T = 3;

Real a.Q;
Real a.P;
Real a.T;

// Equations and algorithms

  // Component 
  // class lab.Inlet
  equation
    a.Q = Q;
    a.P = P;
    a.T = T;
    a.Q = 0.0;

end lab.Inlet;
```

I could see that in the .mof file generated by translation there is one more line: **a.Q = 0.0;**.

So, my question is what is the detailed difference between check and translation? Is there a detailed document for this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking a model should just create a small intermediate model that can be checked for logical errors (#eqs == #unknowns, etc.) but is not used for symbolic manipulations afterwards.

Instantiating a model should create a flat model that can be used for symbolic manipulations.

Translating a model should first run instantiation and afterwards perform symbolic manipulations (BLT, etc.) and actually create simulation code.

OpenModelica kind of does it this way, i can't for sure tell what dymola does, but i guess this gives you an idea. I don't know if there is any further documented explanation for this.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the other answer.

TL:DR;

- Check normally assumes the model will be a sub-component of a larger model.
- Translates is intended for running the model, i.e. the model should be complete in itself.

Longer version:

For "Check" the component is *normally* checked assuming a generic connection to the connector `a` (in general generic connections to all connectors). That connection will add one equation, and thus there will be one equation too many in this model - but we don't know exactly which one.
There are also some additional checks for instantiation, but *normally* missing modifiers (parameter values and redeclarations of partial models) is seen as a non-issue - since it is not a complete model.

For "Translate" it is assumed that you are translating a complete model, and non-causal connectors such as `a` will be default-connected, i.e. flows set to zero - which gives the specific error message you see. (And public top-level inputs would be read from dsu.txt.) Additionally the model is translated to C-code, which requires a bit more.

*Normally* "Check" stops before "Translate" by e.g., not solving systems of equations as indicated in the other answer.

However, in recent versions of Dymola if the model has "experiment" annotation a "Check" will also check that (it is assumed you are checking a complete model) - ignoring the *normally* above.

Recent versions of Dymola will also report issues for the connector `Port`:

> The connector is not balanced, it has 1 flow variables and 2
>   non-causal non-flow variables (including possible over-determined
>   ones).

For "Check" that will be a problem for some models, as Dymola has to add 1 or 2 equations per `Port`-connector.

Comment: For the "ignoring the normally above": there are actually three *normally* in the paragraphs before that. I assume it relates to the one right before it?

Comment: @MarkusA I'll have to verify but it should be all of them.